# Peer nodes of another server not getting connected in private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, enode

I'm doing setup of a private blockchain using PoA, and facing issue in connectivity with peers of another server.

I'm using geth 1.8.16, and created genesis file using puppeth.

Structure

```
Server-1
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
IP: XX.XX.4.5
|-node1 (geth port: 30304)
  |- geth
  |- static-nodes.json
|-node2 (geth port: 30305)
  |- geth
  |- static-nodes.json
|-node3 (geth port: 30306)
  |- geth
  |- static-nodes.json  
|-genesis.json
```

---

```
Server-2
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
IP: XX.XX.4.6
|-node1 (geth port: 30304)
  |- geth
  |- static-nodes.json
|-node2 (geth port: 30305)
  |- geth
  |- static-nodes.json
|-node3 (geth port: 30306)
  |- geth
  |- static-nodes.json  
|-genesis.json
```

static-nodes.json file looks as follows.

```
[
"enode://pubkey@XX.XX.4.5:30304",
"enode://pubkey@XX.XX.4.5:30305",
"enode://pubkey@XX.XX.4.5:30306",

"enode://pubkey@XX.XX.4.6:30304",
"enode://pubkey@XX.XX.4.6:30305",
"enode://pubkey@XX.XX.4.6:30306"
]
```

But the issue is; nodes from same server are connected, but from different server are not getting connected.

From server-1

```
>net.peerCount
2
```

From server-2

```
>net.peerCount
2
```

I have checked that both the server can communicate, so that's not the issue. Ports are also allowed

[image]

Comment: Increase geth's logs verbosity and check for error in the connection. I'd start with a single node in each server.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for your comment! I just found the issue, I need to keep same wallets on the both the server. It is now connecting